# Searching XML elements issue when root element has attributes via XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I want to search the element below from a project file (*.csproj file)

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="C.ClassLibrary3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\Lib\C.ClassLibrary3.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The project file is below, please note the attributes of Project element.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="C.ClassLibrary3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\Lib\C.ClassLibrary3.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" /> 
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup> 
</Project>
```

The code is below:

```
var projectFile = XDocument.Load(projectFilePath);               
var itemGroup = projectFile
.Descendants("ItemGroup")
.Where(x =>x.Elements("Reference").Elements("HintPath").Any())
.ToList();
```

The problem is that the code above only works after the project element is changed to below (remove all attributes.):

```
<Project>
```

What should I do fix the code so the code works and the project remains the original?

Update:

When I add a new element to the file, it automatically add a namespace

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using XElement as following, make sure you specify the namespace for each element you query:

```
XElement xml= XElement.Load("file.xml"); 
XNamespace ns= xml.Name.Namespace; 
var groups = xml.Elements(ns+ "ItemGroup");
```

if you don't want to use `ns` everywhere, you can load the xml, go through all elements and set the namespace attribute to empty string, or you can implement custom method to give you the correct name:

```
public static XNamespace ns =  @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";

public static XName MsElementName(string baseName)
{
    return ns + baseName;   
}
```

and use it like following:

```
var groups = xml.Elements(MsElementName("ItemGroup"));
```

Comment: `XElement xml= XElement.Load("file.xml");
XNamespace ns= xml.Name.Namespace;
var groups = xml.Elements(ns+ "ItemGroup");` what about this one

Comment: It works, but how to avoid repeating ns+ "ItemGroup"? Because, as in  the original post, I have to use ns for many different element names.

Comment: load the xml, set the namespace to empty string and then query the elements without namespace

Comment: do you mean changing the xml fil? The xml cannot be chagned.

Comment: I mean the `XElement` instance, you'll update the object in memory, right after you execute `XElement.Load`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943914.aspx update the namespace(set to empty) for XElement you've loaded from file and work with it later, without further need to specify namespace when querying for descendants

Answer (score 0):

You have a namespace in your `Project` element.So you need to specify it within the element name:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";

var itemGroup = projectFile
               .Descendants(ns +"ItemGroup")
               .Where(x =>x.Elements(ns + "Reference").Elements(ns +"HintPath").Any())
               .ToList();
```

See [`How to: Write Queries on XML in Namespaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669152.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, Like @Andrew suggests, but How to avoid quoting the ns every time?

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could mark more than one answer.